# How to host a self hosted web api in WPF as Self hosted web api is working fine in Console application

Tags: c#, wpf, self-host-webapi

I wanted to host a API in WPF. I have tried implementing Self hosted api using below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

When i have done the implementation for Console application. I was able to verify with PostMan tool to verify get API and it works fine.

But if i implement the same in WPF like below:

MainWindow() in WPF:

```
 string baseAddress = "http://localhost:4444/";
 public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WebApp.Start<StartUp>(baseAddress);
            GetCall();
        }
```

StartUp class:

```
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public class StartUp
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.EnableCors();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
            Owin.CorsExtensions.UseCors(appBuilder,
            Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        }
    }
}
```

GET API implementation like below.

```
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:4444/";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var res = await client.GetStringAsync(baseAddress + "api/demo");
```

After Get API called: I got below exception.

Exception :System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: 'The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.'

Four Inner Exceptions:

- TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
- TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
- IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The
  I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an
  application request..
- SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either
  a thread exit or an application request.

So, I am struggling to find a solution for this. Please provide a solution on this. am i going in the right way or not.

Or Is there any other solution for WPF to host api which will help a lot.

Comment: You need to connect to the  same base URL.  Than your route (see C# at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api#add-the-web-api-and-owin-packages) would be "api/demo"

Comment: @jdweng, Yes, I have used baseURL("http://localhost:4444/api/demo") properly in WPF. It is failing like above exception at GetStringAsync call.

Comment: You are missing "url" and the using statements at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api#start-the-owin-host-and-make-a-request-with-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `DemoController`? If you copied the `ValuesController` class from the example, the URI should be "api/**values**" and nothing else:

```
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:4444/";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var res = await client.GetStringAsync(baseAddress + "api/values");
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a solution from this article.

https://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/09/29/wpf-chrome-embedded-and-webapi-selfhosting/

Now i am able to host api in WPF.